# Python : Deep Reverse List

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list, and I need to reverse every element in the list.

Below is the example :

```
L = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Expected Output :

```
L = [[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

I tried with the below piece of code, it works individually but when I am putting this code within function, then the list is not getting updated.

```
L = [list(reversed(row)) for row in L]

L.reverse()
```

This code works, and the List "L" is getting updated. 
But when I put this code in function

```
def deep_rev(L):

       L = [list(reversed(row)) for row in L]
       L.reverse()

L = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]

deep_rev(L)

print(L)
```

This is returning the same `list = [[0,1,2],[1,2,3]]`

Can anyone please help me in this regard, why in function this is not working?

Comment: You need to return the list at the end of your function. Otherwise the function does nothing

Comment: you are redefining L inside your function, and it stays inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `L = ...` you are assigning a new value to the parameter `L` within the function, without modifying the original list. Instead, you can use `L[:] = ...` to *replace* all the elements in the original list with the values from the new list.

```
def deep_rev(L):
    L[:] = [list(reversed(row)) for row in reversed(L)]

L = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
deep_rev(L)
print(L) # [[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code creates a new list, rather than modifying the exiting list in place. You can make it work, just get rid of the list comprehension and do in-place reversals for the inner lists too:

```
def deep_rev(L):
   for inner in L:
       inner.reverse()
   L.reverse()
```

If you want to support more than two levels of nesting, you could recursively call `deep_rev` on the `inner` lists, rather than just reversing them as I did above. You'd need to check if the values were lists or not, so you'd have a base case.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I find out using recursion:

```
l=[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
def treereverse(l):
    l.reverse()
    for x in l:
        if isinstance(x,list):
            treereverse(x)
    return l
print(treereverse(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code works for your problem,

```
L = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
b=list(reversed(L))
q=[]
for i in b:
    q.append(list(reversed(i)))
print q
```

Output:-

```
 [[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def deep_rev(l):

    l = [list(reversed(row)) for row in l]
    l.reverse()
    return l

l = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]

l = deep_rev(l)

print(l)
```

output

> [[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

`deep_rev(L)` modifies one local list, its scope is inside this function. Either make one deep copy of the list or return the reversed list.